# Android outlined layout with title

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to create a layout that looks like this. This is example of "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout", but I need it to accept multiple elements, buttons, etc. Can anyone help?

P.S. My main problem is to get the title on the line.

[image]

Comment: What you want? can you explain it good

Comment: accept buttons where?

Comment: So i need a layout with border and title like in the picture, and layout can have multiple elements

Answer (score 0):

Do like below

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="@string/label_text"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

For more detail check https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

Comment: he`s using the same material design, please try to read & understand the question good before posting any answers, you can use comment section as well instead of posting answer